# Execute code from a Settings.bundle?

Tags: iphone, ios

I don't think it's generally possible, though I notice some "privileged" apps are able to do it (e.g. Twitter & Facebook). I want to add "Logout" to my iPhone app from inside the Settings.bundle. Currently we do it inside the app itself, but it doesn't really belong there and we've added a screen purely so it can exist, which just feels clunky.

The problem is that while 80% of the logout logic is simply removing some OAuth tokens from the defaults plist, we also need to ping our servers to notify them to drop the device token and stop sending push notifications.

Is it possible to do this from inside the Settings.bundle, or does it need to be inside the app itself? Are Twitter and Facebook apps special cases here, where Apple have allowed them to do things we can't do too?

Comment: As i know, is impossible to run your code from Settings.bundle. You can only change properties of NSUserDefaults. For example, you can create switch property like "Clear token on next application launch" and check this flag on each start.

Comment: Thanks. Requiring the user to open the app isn't an option if we were to put logout inside the Settings.app, since the user would continue to receive push notifications. I guess we'll have to put this in our app, somewhere! :)

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: @AlexR We didn't. I think it's not possible to do, unfortunately.